# CFunctionPointer in Xcode 6.1

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avqueueplayer

Is `CFunctionPointer` supported in `Xcode6`?I am trying to run following code

```
class Queue {

    var desc : AudioStreamBasicDescription
    var queue : AudioQueue?
    init(){}
    func audioQueueHandleBuffer(ctx : UnsafeMutablePointer<()>,
        inAQ : AudioQueue!,
        inBuffer : AudioQueueBufferRef) -> Void{

    }

    func initialize() {
        // this does not work!
        var err = AudioQueueNewOutput(&desc, audioQueueHandleBuffer,   //getting error
            nil, nil, nil, 0, queue)


    }
}
```

But i am getting error.In previous version release note it is explicitly mention that `CFunctionPointer` is not available.But in `Xcode6.1` [release notes](http://adcdownload.apple.com//Developer_Tools/xcode_6.1_gm_seed/xcode_6.1_gm_seed_release_notes.pdf) it is not mention.

How to pass callback in pure swift project.Is there any other way to get buffer in swift?

Comment: You can't treat Swift closures and functions as C function pointers.  see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25341632/pass-c-function-callback-in-swift/26208416#26208416