# Cast a Swift struct to UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>

Tags: swift, casting, void-pointers, unsafe-pointers

Is there a way to cast a Swift struct's address to a void UnsafeMutablePointer?
I tried this without success:

```
struct TheStruct {
    var a:Int = 0
}

var myStruct = TheStruct()
var address = UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>(&myStruct)
```

Thanks!

**EDIT: the context**
I am actually trying to port to Swift the first example in *Learning CoreAudio*.
This is what I have done until now:

```
func myAQInputCallback(inUserData:UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>,
    inQueue:AudioQueueRef,
    inBuffer:AudioQueueBufferRef,
    inStartTime:UnsafePointer<AudioTimeStamp>,
    inNumPackets:UInt32,
    inPacketDesc:UnsafePointer<AudioStreamPacketDescription>)
 { }

struct MyRecorder {
    var recordFile:     AudioFileID = AudioFileID()
    var recordPacket:   Int64       = 0
    var running:        Boolean     = 0
}

var queue:AudioQueueRef = AudioQueueRef()
AudioQueueNewInput(&asbd,
    myAQInputCallback,
    &recorder,  // <- this is where I *think* a void pointer is demanded
    nil,
    nil,
    UInt32(0),
    &queue)
```

I am doing efforts to stay in Swift, but if this turns out to be more a problem than an advantage, I will end up linking to a C function.

**EDIT: bottome line**
If you came to this question because you are trying to use a CoreAudio's AudioQueue in Swift... don't. (read the comments for details)

Comment: Can you add some information *why* the address is needed as a void pointer?

Comment: Sure! I am trying to use CoreAudio in Swift.  
The compiler complains that the arguments passed to AudioQueueNewInput  
are not what they should be, and the struct passed <i>seems</i> to be the cause of that.

Comment: You should add more information and code to the question. Which function exactly, how do you try to call it, the exact error message ...

Comment: I think `AudioQueueNewInput` is not usable in *pure* Swift. You cannot *create* `AudioQueueInputCallback` instance in Swift.

Comment: Thanks rintaro. If it's true, then I am wasting my time... Why then is there this definition in the Apple's doc?
SWIFT
    typealias AudioQueueInputCallback = CFunctionPointer<((UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>, AudioQueueRef, AudioQueueBufferRef, UnsafePointer<AudioTimeStamp>, UInt32, UnsafePointer<AudioStreamPacketDescription>) -> Void)>
This lead me to think that, if you define a regular function with the demanded signature, it would be possible to pass it to the AudioQueueNewInput as an AudioQueueInputCallback.

Comment: Sad to say, you can *receive* `CFunctionPointer` from Obj-C code but cannot *create* it.

Comment: Compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25341632/pass-c-function-callback-in-swift.

Comment: Type `CFunctionPointer` in Xcode and command+click shows: "Though not directly useful in Swift, `CFunctionPointer<T>` can be used to safely pass a C function pointer, received from one C or Objective-C API, to another C or Objective-C API."

Comment: I missed the "Though not directly useful in Swift"... :-)

Comment: And the last lines in the link pointed out by Martin are maybe the most useful to my problem:  
"It's an incredibly painful workaround for a problem that you shouldn't be trying to express in Swift. Code that must manipulate pointers, especially function pointers, is best left in a C or Objective-C file. Otherwise, you're just fighting an unnecessary battle against the language -especially because it has such great support for C and Objective-C interoperability."
Thanks everyone!

Comment: @popisar thanks for great advice not to implement it with swift

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As far as I know, the shortest way is:

```
var myStruct = TheStruct()
var address = withUnsafeMutablePointer(&myStruct) {UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>($0)}
```

But, why you need this? If you want pass it as a parameter, you can (and should):

```
func foo(arg:UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
    //...
}

var myStruct = TheStruct()
foo(&myStruct)
```

Comment: The first variant is really unsafe because the pointer might be used beyond the lifetime of `myStruct`. – If the pointer is needed as an argument to a C function then `withUnsafeMutablePointer(&myStruct) { someCFunction(UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>($0)) }` is also an option.

Comment: We can pass `UnsafeMutablePointer<TheStruct>` as `UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>`. So `withUnsafeMutablePointer(&myStruct) { someCFunction($0) }`  also works.

Comment: @MartinR That why it has "unsafe" in the type name :)

Comment: @Kirsteins: Yes, but there is (in my opinion) still a difference between using the pointer inside the closure, and passing it to the outside.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the method prototypes have been changed as Swift evolved over the years. Here is the syntax for **Swift 5**:

```
var struct = TheStruct()

var unsafeMutablePtrToStruct = withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: &struct) {
    $0.withMemoryRebound(to: TheStruct.self, capacity: 1) {
        (unsafePointer: UnsafeMutablePointer<TheStruct>) in

        unsafePointer
    }
}
```