# Getter for object property needs to return UnsafeMutablePointer<T>?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, pointers

I'm working in Swift and one of the protocols I'm using needs to return an `UnsafeMutablePointer<T>` of a particular object.

I have something like this:

```
@objc var myProperty:UnsafeMutablePointer<someObject>
{
   get
   {
      // I call a class function here to get a 'someObject' 
      // return object which I need to pass back a pointer to it. 

      return UnsafeMutablePointer<someObject>
   }
}
```

The problem is that Xcode doesn't like this. It complains that `'>' is not a unary operator`.

I've also tried removing the `UnsafeMutablePointer<>` and use an `&` in front of `someObject` but it complains that the `&` is to be used immediately in a list of arguments for a function.

I suppose I just can't find the right syntax for this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please show the actual protocol declaration that you are trying to satisfy.

Answer (score 0):

If `someObject` has the type `SomeClass`, then you need to update your declaration like this:

```
@objc var myProperty:UnsafeMutablePointer<SomeClass>
{
   get
   {    
      return UnsafeMutablePointer<SomeClass>(unsafeAddressOf(someObject))
   }
}
```

The generic argument needs to be the type of the returned data, and you also need to intialize a specialized `UnsafeMutablePointer` with the memory address of the desired object.

Comment: I see what you did there. Yes, you assumed correctly. 'SomeClass' is the same type of object as 'SomeObject'.

Comment: I tried what you did before you added the UnsafeAddressOf edit. I was getting this error:  Cannot invoke initializer for type 'UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioStreamBasicDescription>' with an argument list of type '(AudioStreamBasicDescription)'

Comment: Adding the 'unsafeAddressOf' gives me the following error: Argument type 'AudioStreamBasicDescription' does not conform to expected type 'AnyObject'

Comment: @MarioAGuzman, depending on the context, you might not need such a property, especially as `UnsafeMutablePointer` is unsafe to use at later times, take a look at  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29556610/cast-a-swift-struct-to-unsafemutablepointervoid, for example