# DJI Virtual Sticks control from swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, struct, compatibility, dji-sdk

I'm having a really bad time trying to use the DJI-SDK for iOS in Swift.

This SDK is written in Objective-c and uses a key - value system to store values and send commands to the drone, so if y need to tell the drone to enable the virtual sticks you need to execute something like this:

```
DJISDKManager.keyManager()?.setValue(true as NSNumber, for: enableVirtualStickModeKey!, withCompletion: { (error) in......
```

This is pretty straightforward because our value is a `Bool` cast to `NSNumber`, the problems begin when I need to send struct values like a position of the virtual stick (Objective-c struct), this is an example of a value to make the drone ascend at 1 m/s:

```
var controlData = DJIVirtualStickFlightControlData()
    controlData.verticalThrottle = 1
    controlData.pitch = 0
    controlData.roll = 0
    controlData.yaw = 0

DJISDKManager.keyManager()?.setValue(controlData, for: virtualSticksKey!, withCompletion: { (error) in..
```

But the SDK fails with an error trying to set the values.
I wrote to the DJI support team and the answer was that they hope the community can help me solve the problem....

The question is what type of cast I need to make to translate this `DJIVirtualStickFlightControlData` object to an Objective-C compatible type?

This is the `DJIVirtualStickFlightControlData` definition from `DJIFlightControllerBaseTypes.h`

```
    typedef struct
{
    float pitch;
    float roll;
    float yaw;
    float verticalThrottle;
} DJIVirtualStickFlightControlData;
```

And this is the definition of the setValue method from `DJIKeyManager.h`

```
/**
 *  Performs a set on a settable key, changing attributes on the  connected product.
 *  
 *  @param value A value object relevant to the given key
 *  @param key A valid settable key
 *  @param completion A set completion block.
 */
- (void)setValue:(id)value
          forKey:(DJIKey *)key
        withCompletion:(DJIKeyedSetCompletionBlock)completion;
```

Comment: What error is returned for setValue?

Comment: There are ways to transform `struct` to `(NS)Data`, it's an issue not uncommon with Bluetooth Low-Energy. Check there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29556610/cast-a-swift-struct-to-unsafemutablepointervoid ?

Answer (score 1):

Finally I find a workaround to this problem through delegate methods!, actually is a much better way to use the `DJI-SDK` in `SWIFT`

First mark your class as a implementer of `DJIFlightControllerDelegate`

```
class FPVViewController: DJISDKManagerDelegate, DJIFlightControllerDelegate{
```

Create a method to retrieve the FlightController instance

```
func fetchFlightController() -> DJIFlightController?{
        let product = DJISDKManager.product()
        if (product == nil) {
            return nil
        }

        if product!.isKind(of: DJIAircraft.self){
            return (product as! DJIAircraft).flightController
        }
        return nil
    }
```

Call it from the `productConnected` method (this is actually another delegate method from `DJISDKManagerDelegate`) and set this class as the delegate for the FlightController

```
func productConnected(_ product: DJIBaseProduct?) {

    NSLog("Product Connected")

    if (product != nil) {
        //Set this class as the delegate for the hardware

        let flightController = self.fetchFlightController()
        if flightController != nil{
            flightController!.delegate = self
        }

        self.setupVideoPreviewer()
    }

}
```

Before you can send virtual stick commands you must enable them and to do that [some conditions](https://developer.dji.com/api-reference/ios-api/Components/FlightController/DJIFlightController.html?search=virtual&i=2&#djiflightcontroller_virtualstickcontrolmodecategory_isvirtualstickcontrolmodeavailable_inline) must be accomplished

Finally you can set the virtual sticks values this way

```
var controlData = DJIVirtualStickFlightControlData()
    controlData.verticalThrottle = 2
    controlData.pitch = 0
    controlData.roll = 0
    controlData.yaw = 0

let flightController = self.fetchFlightController()
        flightController?.send(controlData, withCompletion: { (error) in
            if error != nil{
                let nserror = error! as NSError
                NSLog("Error controling virtual throttle \(String(describing: nserror))")
            }
        })
```

One more thing: [Xcode remote install and debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44382841/how-do-you-perform-wireless-debugging-in-xcode-9-with-ios-11) is a must have to develop with the `DJI-SDK` is currently in the Beta versions of xCode and iOS but its working perfectly fine

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, please note that the key `SendVirtualStickFlightControlData` is a key of [type Action](http://developer.dji.com/api-reference/ios-api/Components/KeyManager/DJIFlightControllerKey.html). So, the correct way to use the key is to call `.performAction` and not `.setValue`.

To pass a `struct` value in a key, it needs to be wrapped in an `NSValue`. This becomes somewhat tricky with Swift since you have to resort to using the `NSValue` initializer which takes `UnsafeRawPointer`. You can do it like this:

```
var controlData = DJIVirtualStickFlightControlData()
controlData.verticalThrottle = 1
controlData.pitch = 0
controlData.roll = 0
controlData.yaw = 0

let value: NSValue = NSValue.init(pointer: &controlData)

let key = DJIFlightControllerKey(param: DJIFlightControllerParamSendVirtualStickFlightControlData)

DJISDKManager.keyManager()?.performAction(for: key!, withArguments: [value], andCompletion: { (success, value, error) in
    print(success)
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your help aksh1t, I end up using the delegate methods, is easier and you gain a lot of control using the delegate methods to receive the aircraft state updates

Comment: Hi aksh1t, maybe you can help me with this problem?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45872030/retrieve-images-from-a-dji-drone-with-exif-data 
I really appreciate if you can take a look
Thanks!