# Retrieve images from a DJI Drone with EXIF data

Tags: ios, swift, dji-sdk

I'm using the DJISDK in iOS to download pictures from the aircraft.

I'm using the `downloadSelectedFiles` method from `PlaybackManager` class.

Here is my process callback:

```
process: { (data, error) in
    if data != nil{
        if self.downloadedImageData != nil{
            self.downloadedImageData!.append(data!)
        }else{
            self.downloadedImageData = data!
        }

    }
}
```

And this is filecompletition callback:

```
fileCompletion: {
    self.downloadedFilesCount += 1
    let image = UIImage(data: self.downloadedImageData!)
    if let img = image {
        self.downloadedImagesArray?.append(img)
    }
    self.downloadedImageData = nil         
}
```

I'm correctly retrieving the image but without the EXIF data. How can I get that info and add it to the image?
I already downloaded and tried the iOS-MediaManagerDemo and it's the same thing, downloads the image but without the exif data but the official DJI Go app retrieves all the info so there´s must be some way to do it.

Comment: I have no experience with the dji-sdk, but just as a general piece of advice: I wouldn't bet on something being feasible using a certain API, just because the company developing it can do it. A lot of companies use private APIs as well, which other developers have no access to. This might be just the case here as well. But I hope I'm wrong and you'll find a solution.

Comment: Here's a topic that describes your exact same issue (albeit having horribly formatted code): http://forum.dev.dji.com/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=32953

Comment: I digged up a new question from a user in their official forums, which uses `downloadSelectedFiles` instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's also a [similar issue in their forums](http://forum.dev.dji.com/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=32953) regarding empty metadata and `downloadSelectedFilesWithPreparation`. The user that created the post 
also found a solution:

> I solved the problem by not converting the NSData into any format instead saved the NSData directly. Using PHAssets and temporary file to store the NSData as PHAssets only accepts data from URL.

---

Try using [fetchFileDataWithOffset:updateQueue:updateBlock](https://developer.dji.com/api-reference/ios-api/Components/Camera/DJIMediaManager_DJIMedia.html#djimediamanager_djimedia_fetchfiledata_inline) (it will be called `fetchFileData(with:updateQueue:updateBlock)` in Swift)

> [...] fetching the media data will return all data for a video or image

Sample code (objc): [here](https://github.com/MaxwellQi/TVU_DJI/blob/95c73c2bf4aea38f73083410c8a7ac15402415a9/DJISDK4.2.2/Mobile-SDK-iOS-master/Sample%20Code/ObjcSampleCode/DJISdkDemo/Demo/Camera/MediaFetchMedia/CameraFetchMediaViewController.m#L203)

Comment: Saving the Data object directly solved the problem! Thanks!!

Comment: The second solution worked ? So I can update my answer

Comment: Exactly!
I did not even try the first option, Saving the Data object was the easiest way so I try it first and it worked