# DJI iOS SDK downloading multiple images programatically. Camera busy after first download

Tags: swift, download, camera, dji-sdk

Here is my actual code below. It always downloads the first image fine, but gives "Camera is busy or the command is not supported in the camera's current state". I tried with the solution proposed by [How to programmatically download Images from drone using the IOS DJI-SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46101002/how-to-programmatically-download-images-from-drone-using-the-ios-dji-sdk)

I have been struggling with this for the past 10 days and tried all sorts of combination with triggering in async queue etc. but no success. Though DJI samples have a lot of code, they all focus on single download and preview etc. but not the entire raw data with multiple file downloads. Greatly appreciate any help.

```
func downLoad(){
     guard let drone = (DJISDKManager.product() as? DJIAircraft) else {
            testAlert(viewC: self, title: "Message", msg: "Unable to detect Drone", buttonText: "Dismiss")
            return
        }
        // Get camera on drone
        guard  let camera: DJICamera = drone.camera else {
            testAlert(viewC: self, title: "Message", msg: "Unable to detect Camera in initDownload()", buttonText: "Dismiss")
            return
        }
        // check if we can download images with the product
        if !camera.isMediaDownloadModeSupported() {
            testAlert(viewC: self, title: "Message", msg: "Product does not support media download mode", buttonText: "Dismiss")
            return
        }
        camera.setMode( .mediaDownload, withCompletion: {(error) in

            if error != nil {
                self.testAlert(viewC: self, title: "Message", msg: "Error \(error!.localizedDescription)", buttonText: "Dismiss")
            } else {
                // get the media manager from the drone to gain access to the files
                let manager = camera.mediaManager!

                manager.refreshFileList(of: DJICameraStorageLocation.sdCard, withCompletion:  { (error) in
                    if error != nil {
```

**Error here after first download**

```
                        self.testAlert(viewC: self, title: "Message", msg: "Error refreshing list: \(error!.localizedDescription)", buttonText: "Dismiss")
                    }else {

                        // get list of files
                        guard let files = manager.sdCardFileListSnapshot() else {
                            self.testAlert(viewC: self, title: "Message", msg: "No files to download", buttonText: "Dismiss")
                            return
                        }
                        self.downloadImages(files: files, completion: { images in
                            //process images 
                           self.testAlert(viewC: self, title: "Message", msg: "Successfully downloaded all images and count \(images.count)", buttonText: "Dismiss")

                        })//end of downloadImages

                    }// end of else
                }) // end of file-refresh block
            } // end of if else
        })// end of camera setMode block
    }

    func downloadImages(files: [DJIMediaFile], completion: @escaping ([String]) -> Void){
        func downloadNextImage( files: [DJIMediaFile], index: Int = 0, downloadedFileUrls: [String] = []) {
            // stop when we reach the end of the list

            if (index >= files.count - 1)  {
                completion(downloadedFileUrls)
                return
            }
            else {
                var imageData = Data()
                var file = files[index]
                let isPhoto = file.mediaType == DJIMediaType.JPEG || file.mediaType == DJIMediaType.TIFF;

                var previousOffset: UInt = 0

                file.fetchData(withOffset: previousOffset, update: DispatchQueue.main, update: {(_ data: Data?, _ isComplete: Bool, _ error: Error?) -> Void in
                    if let error = error {
                        self.testAlert(viewC: self, title: "Error", msg: "File index : \(index) previousOffset : \(previousOffset) name: \(file.fileName) error : \(error)", buttonText: "Dismiss")
                    }
                    else {
                        imageData.append(data!)
                        previousOffset =  previousOffset + UInt((data?.count)!);
                        if isComplete {
                            if let image = UIImage(data: imageData) {
                                var imageUrl : String = ""
                                if(isPhoto){
                                    imageUrl = saveFile(imag)
                                }else //video
                                {
                                    //process video
                                }
                                downloadNextImage( files: files, index: (index + 1), downloadedFileUrls: downloadedFileUrls + [imageUrl])
                            }// If image
                        } //If complete
                    }// no eroor
                }) // end of filedata fetch
            }   // end of else statement
        }
        // start the recursive function
        downloadNextImage( files: files, index: 0)
    }
```

Comment: Here is the exact error message from "manager.refreshFileList" method after first successful download. "Camera is busy or the command is not supported in the camera's current state (code: -3002)"

Comment: I assume the camera can't refresh the file list while your second download is taking place.  You wouldn't want to anyway, and for the record, it doesn't seem like your code would be, so I'm a little confused myself.